# I am getting Internal Server Error in post request to Json-server using angular

Tags: json, angular, post, json-server

I have the JSON object in json-server

```json
{
      "clubId":1,
      "userName":"firstUser",
      "telephone":"87086757610",
      "placeId":1
    }
```

but when I try make post request I'm getting error Internal Server Error

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInput">UserName</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Name" [ngModel]="userName" name="userName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Telephone Number</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="telephone" [ngModel]="telephone" name="telephone" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Place id is {{placeId}} and Club id is {{clubId}}</h1>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="postUser()">Create</button>
      </form>
```

and component.ts

```
clubId:number;
userName:string;
telephone:string;
placeId: number;

postUser(){
const newUser = {
  clubId: this.clubId,
  userName: this.userName,
  telephone: this.telephone,
  placeId: this.placeId
};
this.userService.createUser(newUser).subscribe(
  (response)=> {
    alert('user created succesfully')
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error)
  }
);
}
```

is there any issue from my code?

userService

```
createUser(user:any){
return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl, user)
}
```

Comment: Internal server error means it's an error in your API not on the frontend side. Please check API log that will give you a proper error message.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the server logs.